# Reading Excel files with OleDb or ExcelDataReader return special characters encoded wronlgy

Tags: c#, excel, encoding, oledb, diacritics

I need to read an EXCEL binary file (xls) in C#.

Basically its working, but i have problems with wrongly encoded characters (german umlauts for example).

Is there some way to specify an encoding? Does Excel files have something like an encoding at all?

The string in the Excel File is

> Lydia Hömmerl

When reading with Jet or EDR i get:

> Lydia HŠmmerl

I have tried OleDb and the [Excel Data Reader](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/) project.

Here is the code i use to open and read the file:

```
var connectionString =
            string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source={0};
                          Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=no\";", filePath);

var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(
          "SELECT * FROM [Webshop orders$]", connectionString);

var ds = new DataSet();     
adapter.Fill(ds, "Orders");
var data = ds.Tables["Orders"].AsEnumerable();
foreach (var row in data)
{
    var str = Convert.ToString(row[0]);
```

Answer (score -2):

[Unicode with C#](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Unicode.aspx)

There are still many people who don't understand the difference between binary and text, or know what a character encoding is, etc. It is for these people that this page has been written. It mentions a few advanced topics, but only to make the reader aware of their existence, rather than to give much guidance on the topic.